# redirect to an url location in php with headers parameters to pass

Tags: php, http, redirect, header

Im trying to translate an url in php. 
My url is something like that :

```
Source : http://www.someserver.com/image.png
```

And I want to redirect it to a server but with a specific header :

```
Destination : http://www.someotherserver.com/image.png
Destination header : X-Auth-Token : somethingsomething
```

The main problem is not downloading the file and just adding the headers parameters (an auth token) and relocate.
So I tried the redirection with the header php command :

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Location: http://www.someotherserver.com/image.png");
```

I tried to add headers but the parameters given to the header command are not duplicated into the location command. How can I pass my header token to this header command?

Comment: if im not mistaken, you want to be using curl

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to redirect it to a server but with a specific header

First of all, you should realize what is the difference between HTTP *Response* Headers and HTTP *Request* Headers.

> ```
> header("Content-Type: image/png");
> header("Location: http://www.someotherserver.com/image.png");
> ```

Those are both *Response* headers that *your server* sends to the *client*.

Since you are instructing the client with the location header to request a new resource, the Content-Type header will be thrown away by the client - nothing to display in response to that request before following the redirect, so content type of no interest.

The client makes a new request to the (other) server in the location header - so any additional *request* headers for that request have to come from the client. Your server has no way of influencing what additional headers the client might send with that request. (Unless you write your own client, that passes received response headers on with his next request.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So headers is not the way to go? Because it makes to say in the header "hey don't look here, go to that location but take that header parameters with you" ?